# positive elements in $L(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

At the moment I'm studying positive elements in $C^*$-algebras. Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space, $L(H)$ the linear bounded operators $H\to H$ and $T^*=T$. Then: 
$$\sigma(T)\subseteq [0,\|T\| ]\; \iff \; \langle Tx,x\rangle\ge 0\; \forall x\in H.$$
I have an idea how to prove $"\Leftarrow"$, but I have no idea how to prove $"\Rightarrow"$.

My try for $"\Leftarrow"$:
T is self-adjoint, therefore it is $\sigma(T)\subseteq \overline{ \{\langle Tx,x\rangle\ge 0; \|x\|=1\}}$. $\Rightarrow \sigma(T)\subseteq \overline{ \{\langle Tx,x\rangle\ge 0; \|x\|=1\}}\subseteq [0,\infty)$. T self-adoint implies that $T$ is normal, therefore it is $\sup\limits_{\lambda\in\sigma(T)}|\lambda|=\|T\|$ and by compactness of $\sigma(T)$, it is $\sup\limits_{\lambda\in\sigma(T)}|\lambda|=\max\limits_{\lambda\in\sigma(T)}|\lambda|=\|T\|$. Then we have $\sigma(T)\subseteq [0,\|T\| ]$. Is it correct?

How to prove the other direction?  I only have: $T$ is self-adjoint, i.e. $\langle Tx,x\rangle=\langle x,Tx\rangle =\overline{\langle Tx,x\rangle}\Rightarrow \langle x,Tx\rangle=\overline{\langle Tx,x\rangle}\Rightarrow \langle Tx,x\rangle\in \mathbb{R}$.

Edit: Now the other direction is clear too, see comments below. 
Regards

Comment: Have you seen the continuous functional calculus? If so, you can apply the square-root function to $T$ if $\sigma(T) \subset [0,\infty)$.

Comment: oh yes, thank you. Now I have an idea how to proof the other direction. But I'm not sure, if everything is correct in my proof of $\Leftarrow$

Comment: Yes, provided you know a proof of the fact that $\sigma(T) \subset \overline{\{\langle Tx,x\rangle : \|x\| = 1\}}$. This is the non-trivial part.

Comment: yes, I know a proof of this fact. Thank you

Comment: As you said that I can apply the square-root function, I remember a theorem we had in lecture which is helpful here. The direction $\Rightarrow$: There exists an element $b\in L(H)$ such that $T=b^*b$, because T is positive. Therefore it is $<b^*bx,x>=<bx,bx>\ge 0$ for all $x\in H$.